Why can't I access my environment secret?
I have configured a dev environment with a Firebase secret, but I can't write it to my .env.local file when running the CI. Only repository-level secrets work.
How can I access my environment secret?

jobs:
  Deploy-Application:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
        -   name: Checkout code
            uses: actions/checkout@v3

        -   name: Create .env file
            run: |
                cd /tmp/app
                touch .env.local
                echo FIREBASE_DSN=${{ secrets.FIREBASE_DSN }} >> .env.local


You have to specify the environment as part of the job:
jobs:
  Deploy-Application:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev  # <-- Here!
    steps:
      # ...


Thanks, it works fine, but github is not able to detect the right environment? I selected the branch on the github environment page, it is useless if I understood correctly? Is it possible not to hardcode "dev" and it automatically detects or do I have to create a ci for each environment? Thanks

@Sofian I'm not sure what you mean by "detect the right environment". What triggers do you run the workflow on? You can set the environment value dynamically; this list shows you which contexts are available to build the value.

@ Benjamin W , I have 3 environments that I created on the github page, dev, staging and prod, each one has variables and secrets, I would like my github action to automatically detect the right secrets rather than hard specifying environment: dev as you showed in the example, I have a little trouble understanding the documentation.

@Sofian What determines which environment is the correct one?

I created 3 environments on the github site and for each I defined branches, for example, if you look at my screenshot above, the dev environment has the develop and feature/* branches

@Sofian And a PR opened into one of these branches should run in the corresponding environment? That's why I asked about the triggers earlier. If you can exactly describe how the environment is determined based on how the workflow is being run, you can codify that into a separate job, which produces the correct environment as its output, and then run a second job in that environment; see Passing information between jobs
